# Post soap xml request with Retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to post an soap xml with Retrofit but it's failing, I'm using a Simple XML Framework to model a SOAP request that looks like this:

**Request XML**

```
@Root(name = "soap12:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix = "xsi"),
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", prefix = "xsd"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "soap12", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
})
@Element(name = "soap12:Body")
public class GeoIP {

    @Namespace(reference = "http://www.webservicex.net/")
    @Element(name="GetGeoIP")
    private GetGeoIP GetGeoIP;

    public GetGeoIP getGetGeoIP() {
        return GetGeoIP;
    }

    public void setGetGeoIP(GetGeoIP getGeoIP) {
        this.GetGeoIP = getGeoIP;
    }

    @Namespace(reference = "http://www.webservicex.net/")
    public static class GetGeoIP{
        @Element(name = "IPAddress")
        private String IPAddress;

        public String getIP() {
            return IPAddress;
        }

        public void setIP(String IP) {
            this.IPAddress = IP;
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetGeoIPResponse xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
      <GetGeoIPResult>
        <ReturnCode>int</ReturnCode>
        <IP>string</IP>
        <ReturnCodeDetails>string</ReturnCodeDetails>
        <CountryName>string</CountryName>
        <CountryCode>string</CountryCode>
      </GetGeoIPResult>
    </GetGeoIPResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**Failure Output**

```
<--- HTTP 500 http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx (2240ms)
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com. D/Retrofit: : HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: Cache-Control: private
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a.mfmpay D/Retrofit: Content-Length: 1188
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 03:22:00 GMT
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1465960929564
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 500
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1465960928849
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
06-15 08:22:09.567 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
                                                                  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
06-15 08:22:09.570 26327-26359/com.a D/Retrofit: <--- END HTTP (1188-byte body)
06-15 08:22:09.571 26327-26327/com.a V/TAG: 500 Internal Server Error
```

**EndPoint Interface**

```
public interface MagentoApi {
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"})
    @POST("/geoipservice.asmx")
    public void requestGeo(@Body GeoIP.GetGeoIP body,Callback<GeoIPResponse> cb);
}
```

**Main Class Code**

```
    GeoIP.GetGeoIP request = new GeoIP.GetGeoIP();
        request.setIP("192.168.1.1");

        RestAdapter restAdapter = getRestAdapter();
        MagentoApi api = restAdapter.create(MagentoApi.class);

        api.requestGeo(request, cb);

retrofit.Callback<GeoIPResponse> cb = new retrofit.Callback<GeoIPResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(GeoIPResponse geoIPResponse, retrofit.client.Response response) {
        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
Log.v("TAG",error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
};
    public static RestAdapter getRestAdapter() {
        Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
        Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://www.webservicex.net")
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter(serializer))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();

        return restAdapter;
    }
```

Comment: can check This link
http://geekcalledk.blogspot.com/2014/08/use-simple-xml-with-retrofit-for-making.html  and 
https://snow.dog/blog/android-and-magento-soap-api-part-ii/

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim already followed but not fruit full for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have made one sample for this kind of webservices. (using webservicex as example, too). You can see it at my [blog](http://blog.asanchez-portfolio.es/en/integracion-retrofit-y-servicios-soap) or in [my github](https://github.com/asanchezyu/RetrofitSoapSample)

UPDATE

Needed libraries:

```
...
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.3.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'){
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
...
```

The sample is for this webservice: http://www.webservicex.net/New/Home/ServiceDetail/42

First of all, you have to create Retrofit instance:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();

Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer))
        .baseUrl("http://www.webservicex.net/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

After that, you have to create the API object:

```
    public interface UsStatesApi {

    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: text/xml",
            "Accept-Charset: utf-8"
    })
    @POST("/uszip.asmx")
    Call<UsStatesResponseEnvelope> requestStateInfo(@Body UsStatesRequestEnvelope body);

}
```

For creating your entities, you have to annotate them correctly. These are the request classes (response classes are made in the same way):

class: UsStatesRequestEnvelope

```
@Root(name = "soap12:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace( prefix = "xsi", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "xsd", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "soap12", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
})
public class UsStatesRequestEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soap12:Body", required = false)
    private UsStatesRequestBody body;

    public UsStatesRequestBody getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(UsStatesRequestBody body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

class : UsStatesRequestBody

```
@Root(name = "soap12:Body", strict = false)
public class UsStatesRequestBody {

    @Element(name = "GetInfoByState",required = false)
    private UsStatesRequestData usStatesRequestData;

    public UsStatesRequestData getUsStatesRequestData() {
        return usStatesRequestData;
    }

    public void setUsStatesRequestData(UsStatesRequestData usStatesRequestData) {
        this.usStatesRequestData = usStatesRequestData;
    }
}
```

class: UsStatesRequestData

```
@Root(name = "GetInfoByState", strict = false)
@Namespace(reference = "http://www.webserviceX.NET")
public class UsStatesRequestData {

    @Element(name = "USCity", required = false)
    private String city;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I implemented as your solution and It worked. But I got some problem that when the @Body contain some field that have value as XML string (mine is rawData with value is XML string), the value of that field was encoded like:

 "rawData>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;ws:login&gt;&lt;userName&gt;2</rawData>

How to prevent that encoded ? 
I've some similar issues on stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378269/how-to-disable-a-body-data-getting-encoded-in-soap-retrofit-request

Can you give me some idea if have ?

Comment: Could you please answer to thes Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808494/soap-api-calling-with-retrofit-getting-null-body-in-android

Comment: Your blog is not working. Please update the URL.