# How to disable a body data getting encoded in soap, retrofit request

Tags: android, xml, soap, retrofit2

I have a request data where one of the element takes xml as value. While sending the data to the server using **@Body** my inner xml is getting encoded(html encoded). Because of this service is failing in server side. How to disable the inner **xml getting encoded**.

sample:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap12:Body>
      <UpdateASN xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <SecureCode>VkdWelkyOUJVMDQ9</SecureCode>
         <strXML>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;NewDataSet&gt;&lt;Table&gt;&lt;ASNId&gt;21131248&lt;/ASNId&gt;&lt;ASNLineId&gt;108069195&lt;/ASNLineId&gt;&lt;EANOCC&gt;5051622303470&lt;/EANOCC&gt;&lt;TUQuantityRecevied&gt;2&lt;/TUQuantityRecevied&gt;&lt;ItemDescription&gt;sample 6X300ML&lt;/ItemDescription&gt;&lt;TUSize&gt;6&lt;/TUSize&gt;&lt;TUDespatched&gt;1&lt;/TUDespatched&gt;&lt;/Table&gt;&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;]]&gt;</strXML>
      </UpdateASN>
   </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @user1344655 did you resolve this ?

Comment: @Dolphin forming the inner xml Without CDATA it worked.

Comment: @user1344655 I don't get your point. can you give me more detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it by myself.

Here is what I'm doing, I have removed enclosing the inner xml inside `CDATA` so that in server side it can take and decode the inner xml before processing.

If we enclose the inner xml with `CDATA` it won't decode the string and it make service to fail.

Here is my final request:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap12:Body>
      <UpdateASN xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <SecureCode>VkdWelkyOUJVMDQ9</SecureCode>
         <strXML>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;NewDataSet&gt;&lt;Table&gt;&lt;ASNId&gt;21131248&lt;/ASNId&gt;&lt;ASNLineId&gt;108069195&lt;/ASNLineId&gt;&lt;EANOCC&gt;5051622303470&lt;/EANOCC&gt;&lt;TUQuantityRecevied&gt;2&lt;/TUQuantityRecevied&gt;&lt;ItemDescription&gt;sample 6X300ML&lt;/ItemDescription&gt;&lt;TUSize&gt;6&lt;/TUSize&gt;&lt;TUDespatched&gt;1&lt;/TUDespatched&gt;&lt;/Table&gt;&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</strXML>
      </UpdateASN>
   </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```