# How can I prevent String getting encoded when making a Soap request using Retrofit2

Tags: android, xml, soap, retrofit

I'm trying to pass a soap request like this:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <Data>data='a' & type='b'</Data>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but it actually sent:

```
<Data>data=&apos;a&apos; &amp; type=&apos;b&apos;</Data>
```

Retrofit encodes `&` and `'` to `&amp;` and `&apos;`

so I can't even replace `'` with `&apos;`

here is my Rrtrofit setting:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(URL)
    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

How do I deal with this.

Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instruct your parser to treat content inside `<data>` as `CData`.
I'm not sure which XML parser you'r using but, most of XML parsers has provision for `CDATA'. Do some exploration. Your XML will look like below. This will ensure no conversion of special characters.

```
<soap:Envelope>
 <soap:Body>
  <Data><![CDATA[ data='a' & type='b']]></Data>
 </soap:Body>
```

Refer [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_cdata_sections.htm) for more details.

Comment: thanks for helping, but it's being encoded to:
 `&lt;![CDATA[ data=&apos;a&apos; &amp; type=&apos;b&apos;]]&gt;`
like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378269/how-to-disable-a-body-data-getting-encoded-in-soap-retrofit-request

Comment: @raxabizze thats incorrect way of putting `CDATA`. If you refer correct answer of stackoverflow link of your comment, answer says corect way of `CDATA`. You must be producing `XML` like I mentioned in answer. Try various options of your parser, it should work.