# How can i read the dataset and show on android application with soap web service?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I need an android application i have soap web service and ı can read DATASET from database with web service and i can display them in web page but ishould display this datas on androidd application but i couldnt how can i do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post soap xml request with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825990/post-soap-xml-request-with-retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle both HTTP requests and Parsing XML.

But this question can be a possible duplicate of this:
[Post soap xml request with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825990/post-soap-xml-request-with-retrofit?answertab=votes#tab-top)