# WorkManager or Foreground Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, android-background, android-thread

Once the user gets into an activity, I need to send a value to the Web Service and, once s/he exits the activity, I need to send another value to the server. It needs to happen at that exactly moment.
[Android Developers guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) says I should use Foreground Services for background tasks which need to be executed immediately, and WorkManager for deferable tasks. However, I do not need to update anything on the UI nor a notification (as they are mandatory in Foreground services) after the task is done...

What should I use?

Comment: don't use any of those just send it as immediate request

Comment: what object would you use then to send the value to the WebService?? I mean, the background request should be encapsulated into an object able to work in background (askynctask, thread, workmanager, etc...) which one should i use?@FahadAlotaibi

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE:

As said in the comment

> OnDestroy is not even guarenteed to be called on process death and moreover. The correct approach is a foreground service that shows some generic "syncing with server" message until it's done

Comment: what object would you use then to send the value to the WebService?? I mean, the background request should be encapsulated into an object able to work in background (askynctask, thread, workmanager, etc...) which one should i use?

Comment: To send request to your API, you could use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit). Asynctask are now deprecated

Comment: it is not an API, is a webservice accessed by usihg HttpTransportSE and SoapObject objects @Biscuit

Comment: You can use retrofit to make calls those calls : [post soap xml request with retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825990/post-soap-xml-request-with-retrofit)

Comment: DON'T do this.  OnDestroy is not even guarenteed to be called on process death and moreover.  The correct approach is a foreground service that shows some generic "syncing with server" message until it's done.